# Pipe symbol in elm action method

Tags: haskell, elm

```
update action model =
    case action of
      Delete id ->
          { model | tasks <- List.filter (\t -> t.id /= id) model.tasks }
```

I don't understand this syntax,

```
  { model | .......... }
```

What does the pipe symbol `|` do here?

What does flower brackets `{}` mean? And does the action `Delete` return any value?

This code is taken from elm's Todo [tutorial](https://github.com/evancz/elm-todomvc/blob/master/Todo.elm#L114).

Comment: "Flower brackets" — nice 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is record update syntax: http://elm-lang.org/docs/records#updating-records

`{ model | tasks <- value }` returns `model` record with `tasks` field set to a new value.